# Трэкинг нескольких клиентов java + websocets php

Tags: php, java, android, yandexmapkit

Вопрос заключается в том, что я получаю при изменении/коннекте клиента его координаты, и создаю плэйсмарк в яндекс картах, получаю данные через веб сокет сервер, вопрос, как изменить координаты точки, при получении новых координат от пользователя и также изменить координаты этой точки у других клиентов, т.к эти координаты никак не связанны, и, в принципе нельзя повесить плэйсмарк на человека, если нужно - вот код того, как создаю плейсмарки

```
try {
    runOnUiThread(() -> {
        mapView.getMap().getMapObjects().addPlacemark(new Point(rootGeolocation.getLatitude(), 
        rootGeolocation.getLongitude()),  ImageProvider.fromResource(HomeActivity.this, 
        R.drawable.geolocation));
    });
} catch (Exception e){
    Log.d("geoCatch", e.getMessage());
}
```

сервер сокетов написан на php с использованием библиотеки воркерман

Comment: А почему метки не могут иметь IDшники, жёстко связанные с конкретными юзерами и почему тогда не менять координаты конкретным меткам, как получаете по ним свежие координаты? Ну и к слову, сценарии с отслеживанием у Яндекса требуют платный ключ MapKit.

Comment: Я, немного подумав, придумал такую систему: все координаты хранятся в предисе, далее джсоном кодируются, и отправляются на клиент, (у каждого клиента уникальный хэш), и далее создаю хэшмап в котором хранится ключ - хэш юзера, значение - плейсмарк, при получении новых данных, предис обновляет хэш и отправляет новые данные, а на клиенте по хэшу уже изменяется определенный плейсмарк, пока мне кажется этот план хорошим, как закончу напишу развернутый ответ как я это реализовал Добавил обертку предиса для того, чтобы при подключении клиента все пользователи сразу выводились а не только при апдейте

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Итак, лучше поздно чем никогда

Я отправляю по вебсокетам данные о геопозиции (листенером) на сервер, с сервера обрабатываю предисом данные и отправляю хэшем всем клиентам, дальше паршу ответ, делаю из него хэш и изменяю позицию точки.

Пример логики выглядит так:
Есть 2 экрана: для людей за которыми ведется трекинг(Т), и для людей которые следят(С). Также есть хэш для каждого пользователь(уникальный)

Отправляется с экрана Т данные на сервер по вебсокет соединению, там, заносится его хэш в список предиса, дальше формируется хэш из данных :

```
$redis->hmset($decode['Hash'], array(
        "Longitude" => $decode['Longitude'],
        "Latitude" => $decode['Latitude'],
        "DC" => $decode['DC'],
        "Hash" => $decode['Hash'])
        );
```

кодируется и отправляется клиенту приконнектившемуся, дальше, при след отправки данных, если есть хэш в листе, то данные просто обновляется и приходит уже не массив клиентам, а строка. Массив парсится на строне С и заносится в бд как

```
List<String, Object> places = new HashMap<>;

places.add(parce.get("Hash"), addPlacemark);
```

Если приходит строка с изменениями, ищем по ключу нужный элемент массива и сдвигаем точку.

Также с сервера ведется пингование, и при отключении, посылается строк вида

```
{"Exit": "HashU"}
```

Из этого мы удаляем плейсмарк и хэш из списка

Надеюсь, кому-то помог, удачного коддига